# Advantages of .contains() and splitting a string to compare?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I've a file with around 500 000 lines. Every line has the following form: 'a date # content'. I want to compare the date to a given date and I used to read every single line, `.split(' # ')` it into a `String[]` and compared the date with `if(lineString[0].equals(givenDate)){...}`. Now that the content doesn't contain a date it my be sufficient to use `if(lineString.contains(givenDate)){...}`. So are there any advantages (runtime, efficiency) or any difficulties I should know about?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers and explanations. `.startsWith` seems to be the best solution.

Comment: What is the format of the date?

Comment: `.contains()` is more efficient because it will be able to exit early, no extra memory is required, etc.

Comment: `split(" # ")` traverses the entire String and then copies it into parts, meaning you go over each line twice. The `contains` method only goes over the String once, so that should be faster.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: `.equals` will immediately exit because if the string doesn't start with the correct characters, it can exit, whereas `.contains` will keep searching for the date until the end of the line.

Comment: @CommuSoft: that is if you look at a single entry in the array in a vacuum. He will still traverse every single entry in the array. Granted though: they both exit early in their own way then.

Comment: If you read half a million lines from a file and check every line, the difference between `contains()` and `equals()` is unlikely to matter. But of course you need to measure first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most efficient way is [**`.startsWith`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm). It will only read the characters to the end of the time format, and will also break off search from the moment one character differs.

## Why not `.split`?

Split iterates over the line to the end, this because it aims to split the string in an arbitrary number of parts, so it is possible that there is a `#` at the end of the string.

## Why not `.contains`?

Same reason: it will keep trying to match the date in the string. Furthermore it is even possible that there is a date stored somewhere in the middle of the text, in that case you can thus even match lines that are technically not correct.

For instance - here making a small assumption about the format - if the line reads:

```
20141231 # Scheduled an appointment with Tim on 20150115
```

Then searching for `20150115` will result in a match, although the line has something to do with that date, it is not posted on that date.

Comment: `startsWith()` is definitely the quickest to bail out.

Comment: @CommuSoft for me `.startsWith` seems to be the way to go. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`split` uses [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `Matcher` [behind the covers](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), but for very simple cases (which yours might be). For arbitrary regexes, it is usually more efficient to compile the pattern and reuse it for each string in your file if your split string is a regex. In your case I agree that `startsWith` might be the most efficient. The code is a lot tighter and there are no considerable memory allocations.